# Search on multi index in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I want to search objects in Elasticsearch which are combination of two index.
Is there a way to search on two index with specific condition on them?

for example:
I have an index `siem-referencedata-list` with lists' metadata. each documents have a subset index base on its id (`siem-referencedata-list-documentsId`)

how could I set a query that check `siem-referencedata-list` and its subsets?

I have below query for `siem-referencedata-list`

```json
POST siem-referencedata-list/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "query_string": {
                  "default_field": "list.name",
                  "query": "*list1*",
                  "default_operator": "OR"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "query_string": {
                  "default_field": "list.type",
                  "query": "*Keyword*",
                  "default_operator": "OR"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and also I have below query for indexes base on above documents' id (`siem-referencedata-list-*)

```json
POST siem-referencedata-list-*/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "query_string": {
                  "query": "*30.3.30.3*"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

How can I set a query to combine them?
search items on `siem-referencedata-list` and also on `siem-referencedata-list-*` and result items that are both results.

I set two different query and get two different arrays. How can I get intersection of these two arrays?

Comment: You should maybe give some basic example of what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added specific word `column-` into documents of indexes "siem-referencedata-list-*" and I separated query function of "siem-referencedata-list" and its subsets..

```
POST siem-referencedata-list/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "query_string": {
                  "query": "*list1*",
                  "fields": ["column-*"]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is a workaround add a property to documents in this specific index **"siem-referencedata-list"** while indexing
and use that property to query the documents